# ¿Cómo calcular el Z-SCORE en Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

estoy intentando calcular el z-score para un conjunto de datos en power bi, pero tengo algunos problemas con el calculo del promedio:

```
z-score = Distancia Total - promedio (dist total) / Desviacion Standar
```

En la foto que adjunto, se puede ver la columna Microciclo (abajo c/ jugador); Distancia Total (Distancia acumulada en esa semana), mean_td (promedio de la distancia total);z-score

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que encuentro es que la columna mean_td me calcula la media diaria de cada jugador y no la media de la semana 15 de todos los jugadores.(adjunto  calculo manual en excel)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las formulas creadas hasta el momento:

```
mean_TD = CALCULATE(AVERAGEX('DB', 'DB'[TOT DIST]), ALLEXCEPT('DB','DB'[MICROCICLO]))

sd_TD = CALCULATE(STDEVX.P('DB', 'DB'[TOT DIST]), ALLEXCEPT('DB', 'DB'[MICROCICLO]))

z-sore_TD = (CALCULATE(SUM('DB'[TOT DIST]) - [mean_TD]) / [sd_TD])
```

Gracias